# Spark ssh password-less with different username

Tags: apache-spark, ssh

I am trying to ssh to start a slave on a remote machine but when I run the command `start_slaves` it output

```
 remote_server_hostname: local_machine_user_name@remote_server_hostname: Permission denied (publickey).
```

So the reason it does not work is that it should be `remote_machine_user_name` instead of `local_machine_user_name`. I have put my `rsa_id.pub` in the remote server `authorized_keys` file. Does somebody know where should I set this different user name in Spark please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try putting the following lines in the `~/.ssh/config` file on your local machine. Then try setting Spark to connect to the aliased host (`remote_server_alias`) when you set up the slaves.

```
Host remote_server_alias
    User remote_machine_user_name
    Hostname remote_server_hostname
```